# How do I remove square brackets for all the values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, brackets

I have a column named keywords in my pandas dataset. The values of the column are like this :

```
[jdhdhsn, cultuere, jdhdy]
```

I want my output to be

```
jdhdhsn, cultuere, jdhdy
```

Comment: `df['keywords'].str.join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
keywords = [jdhdhsn, cultuere, jdhdy]
if(isinstance(keyword, list)):
    output = ','.join(keywords)
else:
    output = keywords[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The column of your dataframe seems to be a list

Lists are formatted with brackets and each elements of that list's **repr**()

Pandas has built in functions for dealing with strings

`df['column_name'].str` let's you use each element in the column and apply a str function on them. Just like `', '.join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])`

Thus `df['column_name_str'] = df['column_name'].str.join(', ')` will produce a new column with the formatting you're after.

You can also use the `.apply` to perform arbitrary lambda functions on a column, such as:

`df['column_name'].apply(lambda row: ', '.join(row))`

But since pandas has the `.str` built in this isn't needed for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = ["[jdhdhsn, cultuere, jdhdy]"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["keywords"])
new_df = df['keywords'].str[1:-1]
print(df)
print(new_df)
```